# Error using jr cc, label (value out of range)

Tags: assembly, dynamic-c

```
*Error: value xxx is out of range, valid values are between -128 and 127.
```

I've been having this error in all my code.

The instruction `jr cc, label` explains this:

> Note that the relative jump has a limited range of [-128, 127] from
>   the address of the first byte of the instruction following the JR
>   instruction.

I tried putting the instruction `nop` after `jr` but still got this error.

Maybe it is that I don't understand well how this works. If someone could explain me more (or give examples) it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Your jump target is too far. Reverse the conditional jump and use that to skip over a longer range unconditional jump.

Comment: I take it this is a Z80-compatible architecture? If so try `JP` instead of `JR` for an unlimited branch range, at the expense of an extra byte.

Answer (score 0):

Out of range problem can be solved by changing the **relative jump (jr)** to an **absolute jump (jp)**.

> Jump relative (JR) instructions allow easier code relocation because
>   the jump is relative to the current program counter. For example, RAM
>   functions are usually written in assembly and are relocated to RAM
>   from flash. **A jump (JP)** instruction would not work in this case
>   because the jump would be to **a flash location** and not the intended
>   RAM location. Using **JR** instead of JP will jump to the intended
>   **RAM location**.